# pandas sort and reindexing after concat

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes. The one is head-part + odd-part and the other is even-part of id.
The process is as below.

1.merge two data.

2.sort data.

3.reindex.

my sample data set is below.

```
id  orgName people  repos   crt_at
34716   1176774 zatecusweb  0   0   2011-11-07T01:01:49Z
```

even- part is even number of id and the other part is odds.

But sort is not active.
It needs to reset_index.
Why is this happening?

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('./Data/orgs_cnt.csv',quotechar='|')
df2 = pd.read_csv('./Data/orgs_cnt2.csv',quotechar='|')
df = pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True) 
df = df.sort_values('id')
df = df.reindex(np.arange(len(df)))
# df = df.reset_index()
plt.plot(df.id)
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Y2a8.png)

Comment: provide data sample and don't post images

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'id' : [1, 3, 5,7], 'values' : [79, 56, 44,75]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'id' : [2, 4, 6,8], 'values' : [69, 75, 78,95]})

listdf = [df1, df2]

data = pd.concat(listdf)

data.sort_values(by='id', inplace=True)

data = data.reset_index(drop=True)

plt.plot(data.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `sort_values('id', axis=1)`?
[sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) needs to know how to sort, axis=1 means columns.
A data sample would be helpful ^_^.

Comment: I add sample data :). sorry, for so late.>